# create csv file from dict

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hello my question is how to save my dictionary in a csv file , I have managed to collect data from diffrent excel files and save it in a dictionary here's the code :

```
import os
from os import walk
import pandas as pd 


path = r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\IOMTest'
my_files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
my_files.extend([os.path.join(dirpath, fname) for fname in filenames])

print(my_files)

all_dicts_list = []
for file_name in my_files:

#Display sheets names using pandas
pd.set_option('display.width',300)
mosul_file = file_name
xl = pd.ExcelFile(mosul_file)
mosul_df = xl.parse(0, header=[1], index_col=[0,1,2])

#Read Excel and Select columns

mosul_file = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = 0 , 
index_clo=None, na_values= ['NA'], usecols = "A, E, G, H , L , M" )

#Remove NaN values

data_mosul_df = mosul_file.apply (pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
data_mosul_df = mosul_file.dropna()

#Save to Dictionary

datamosulx = data_mosul_df.to_dict()
all_dicts_list.append(datamosulx)
print(datamosulx)
```

My question is how to save

```
datamosulx = data_mosul_df.to_dict()
all_dicts_list.append(datamosulx)
```

As a csv file ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if `somedict` is your dictionary, you can use something like this:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(somedict.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to below two formats to convert pandas to dictionary.

Also It is one of the most widely used modules in python.

Type 1: Dictionary with list as values.

```
import pandas as pd

struct = {'ID' : ['1','2','3'], 'COST' : ['10','20','30']}
pd.DataFrame(struct).to_csv('Test.csv',header=True,index=False)
```

Type 2: List containing dictionaries with matching keys.

```
import pandas as pd

struct = [{'ID': '1', 'COST': '10'}, {'ID': '2', 'COST': '20'},{'ID': '3', 'COST': '30'}]
pd.DataFrame(struct).to_csv('Test.csv',header=True,index=False)
```

We use these structure in order to provide a structure to our data.

Learning References Link : https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

Comment: the Dictionary with list as values is the one that i need how ever i am not sure ho to link it to my all_dicts_lists I have tried the following code but it seems to not work , i want to arrange my data by columns : `datamosulx =[] struct = {'Place ID' : [], 'Families' : [], 'Latitude' : [], 'Longitude' : [], 'Location Name' : [], 'Individuals' : [] } pd.DataFrame(struct).to_csv(r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\IOMTest\datamosulxx.csv',header=True,index=False)` any hints ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

on dataframe object call `to_csv('new_csv_filename.csv')` function.

Try following code:

```
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(all_dicts_list)
final_dataframe.to_csv('new_csv_filename.csv')
```

Comment: Hi this code works well however i am trying to structure my data by column but it's not working `datamosulx =[]    
struct = {'Place ID' : [], 'Families' : [], 'Latitude' : [], 'Longitude' : [], 'Location Name' : [], 'Individuals' : [] }
pd.DataFrame(struct).to_csv(r'C:\Users\Sarah\Desktop\IOMTest\datamosulxx.csv',header=True,index=False)`

Comment: Hi, I executed that code in jupyter, the csv file is  also getting created  and the columns are at the top horizontally left to right. with empty rows..

Comment: Yes how to make the empty rows filled with the data that are inside my dictionary datamosulx ?

Comment: if you want to pass a dictionary as a data to csv file then, one important  point must be clear that is, when you pass dictionary into Dataframe() then, the keys will be treated as column and the values will be treated as rows,    so what you can do is instead of creating  columns through this `pd.DataFrame(struct)` add keys in your dictionary `datamosulx` as a structure columns (Place ID,Families etc) as a per your requirement. and finally pass that dictionary into DataFrame `pd.DataFrame(datamosulx).to_csv('path\csv_filename.csv')`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of dict.

```
import csv

records = [{'first_name': 'Arun', 'age': 27, 'location': ['KL', 'IN']},
 {'last_name': 'N A', 'first_name': 'Samuel', 'age': 30}] #  Input. Here we have two rows and lets take the keys as column name.

heading_set = {k for row in records for k in list(row)} # Doing this since the keys are different in the given dict
print(f"heading is: {heading_set}")

with open('example1.csv', 'w') as opcsv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(opcsv, fieldnames=list(heading_set))
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in records:
        for key in list(row):
            if type(row.get(key)) == list:
                row[key] = ",".join(row[key])
        writer.writerow(row)
```